# database configuration error with following error :- /usr/share/freeswitch/scripts/db_connect.lua:3: module 'luasql.postgres' not found

Tags: postgresql, lua, ubuntu-14.04, freeswitch

lua postgres integration error with no module found with postgres module not found. I have tried following :-

1. package **lua-sql-postgres** installed
2. package **lua dpi-DATABASE** installed
3. freeswitch postgres core packages

Comment: Which lua version are you using?

Comment: praveen@praveen-300E4C-300E5C-300E7C:~$ lua -v

Lua 5.1.5  Copyright (C) 1994-2012 Lua.org, PUC-Rio